# Map hibernate association as a Java.util.Map

Tags: hibernate

I'm trying to map a hibernate association as a Java.util.Map. 
The channel table has a column merchant_account_id
Merchant account table doesn't reference back to the channel table. It only has merchant_account_id, param_name and param_value. merchant_account_id can appear more than once, with different param_name values.

What am I doing wrong? the map is empty unless merchant_account_id appears only once in merchant account table.

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "P", name = "CHANNEL")
public class ChannelEntity implements ProcessingChannel, PersistentEntity<Long> {

  private enum ParamName {
    SE_NUMBER,
    SUBMITTER_ID
  }

  @Id
  @Column(name = "CHANNEL_ID")
  private Long id;

  @OneToMany(targetEntity = MerchantAccountEntity.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumn(name = "MERCHANT_ACCOUNT_ID")
  @MapKey(name = "id.paramName")
  private Map<String, MerchantAccountEntity> merchantAccount = new HashMap<>();

  public Map<String, MerchantAccountEntity> getMerchantAccount() {
    return merchantAccount;
  }

  @Override
  public String getSeNumber() {
    return getStringValue(ParamName.SE_NUMBER);
  }

  @Override
  public String getSubmitterId() {
    return getStringValue(ParamName.SUBMITTER_ID);
  }

  private String getStringValue(ParamName paramName) {
    if (merchantAccount.containsKey(paramName.name())) {
      return merchantAccount.get(paramName.name()).getParamValue();
    }
    return null;
  }
}


@Entity
@Table(schema = "P", name = "MERCHANT_ACCOUNT")
public class MerchantAccountEntity implements MerchantAccount, PersistentEntity<String> {

  @EmbeddedId
  private MerchantAccountEntityPK id;

  @Column(name = "PARAM_VALUE")
  private String paramValue;

  @Override
  public String getId() {
    return id.getId();
  }

  @Override
  public String getParamName() {
    return id.getParamName();
  }

  @Override
  public String getParamValue() {
    return paramValue;
  }
} 

 @Embeddable
 public class MerchantAccountEntityPK implements Serializable {

      private static final long serialVersionUID = 4598402273070888330L;

      @Column(name = "MERCHANT_ACCOUNT_ID")
      private Long merchantAccountId;

      @Column(name = "PARAM_NAME")
      private String paramName;


      public String getId() {
        return merchantAccountId + "+" + paramName;
      }

      public String getParamName() {
        return paramName;
      }   
 }
```